# Parsing XML with defined schema in coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a XML document like this:

```
<cfset local.xml = xmlParse("<file_path>")>
<cfset local.getClassID = xmlSearch(local.xml, "//class/id")>
<cfdump var="#local.getClassID#">
```

**XML DOC**:

```
<ou_schedule xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/xmlns" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="<XSD url>">
    <schedule>
        <category>
            <id>Test Data</id>
            <name>Test Data</name>
            <classes>
                <class>
                    <id>Test Data</id>
                    <title>Test Data</title>
                    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
                    <duration>Test Data</duration>
                    <price>Test Data</price>
                    <instruction_language>Test Data</instruction_language>
                    <start_date>Test Data</start_date>
                    <start_time>Test Data</start_time>
                    <end_time>Test Data</end_time>
                    <location>Test Data</location>
                    <city>Test Data</city>
                    <customer_sat_flag>Test Data</customer_sat_flag>
                    <activity_version_id>Test Data</activity_version_id>
                    <event_id>Test Data</event_id>
                </class>
            </classes>
        </category>
    </schedule>
</ou_schedule>
```

I am getting an `empty array` every time. When I removed all attributes from root node i.e., 
`<ou_schedule>` then I was getting correct results. 
What am I missing?

Please help .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it has a namespace, if you change your XPath to be "//:class/:id", it should ignore the namespace in your root node.

```
<cfset local.getClassID = xmlSearch(local.xml, "//:class/:id")>
```

It seems the :node syntax was changed in CF10.  I found this [Bug Report](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3377581) talking about it.

I just tested the :class/:id on CF9 and it worked, but it broke on CF10.  I modified the xpath a little to this, and it worked for me on CF9 and 10.

```
<cfset local.getClassID = xmlSearch(foo, "//*[local-name() = 'class']/*[local-name() = 'id']")>
```

Comment: I am getting error. `Unable to process the result of the XMLSearch for Unexpected colon at start of token.`

Comment: What is your version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Currently I am using CF 10 but I need it to work on CF 9 as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I haven't tested this on Lucee.

Comment: Good stuff! Ran into this on CF10 and your fix did the trick.